# Why is my swift code pausing at the loading screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

```
if timerRunning == false{
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timerRunning = true
}
while timerLabel.text != "0"{
gameViewStillRunning = false
}
if gameViewStillRunning == false{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
}
```

The purpose of this code is to display a label counting down, and then when it hits 0, the scene should switch to a different ViewController. This code doesn't get any errors but when I run it, the program does not get any further than the loading screen. Any suggestions?

Comment: What screen do you mean by "the loading screen"?  Are you seeing the screen with the label that you're supposedly updating here?  (The one with `timerLabel`?)

Comment: should probably include more code, you're not decrementing your counter in this code, that should all be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running a `while` loop on the main thread which is also the thread responsible for drawing the UI. As long as that thread is stuck in your while loop there's no way for it's run loop to continue and no opporunity for it to update the display or respond to user interaction.

In addition if you look at the `NSTimer` documentation you might notice that `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` states that it `Creates and returns a new NSTimer object and schedules it on the current run loop in the default mode.` That timer is scheduling a call to your `counting` function in the main thread's run loop but since that thread is stuck spinning forever in your `while` it will never have a chance to execute so it has no chance to update that `timerLabel.text`.

Rather than attempting to block execution with your `while` loop while polling for some condition, a better solution would be to allow the run loop to continue and to react when the timer calls your `counting` function. Let your application react to events (like the time remaining changing) regardless of when or how they happen rather than trying to control the exact sequence of execution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this is an infinite loop:

```
while timerLabel.text != "0"{
    gameViewStillRunning = false
}
```

The body of the loop doesn't change the value of `timerLabel.text`, so the condition (the test in the first line) keeps failing, and the loop just loops forever — and the code, and so the entire app, just hangs at that point, coming to a dead stop permanently.

Comment: Infinite loops are always a danger, and one of the most fundamental errors a programmer can make. There is a reason why Apple's address in Mountain View, California is One Infinite Loop.